# Is grub verify Linux image?

Tags: secure-boot

I have EFI system with my own keys and Canonical keys in db. Today I realize that EFI system or grub allows to run unsigned kernel. Is that good? I have a `vmlinuz-4.8.0-27-lowlatency.efi.signed` which is signed by Canonical and `vmlinuz-4.8.0-28-lowlatency` which is unsigned. Both is working. But how? Is Secure Boot should be break load unsigned kernel?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/SecureBoot#Verifying_the_signature_on_a_signed_PE.2FCOFF_or_signed_kernel_image . It will boot an unsigned kernel and unsigned kernel modules if secure boot is disabled in your bios.

Comment: "confirm that Secure Boot was enabled by reading /sys/kernel/security/securelevel, which will contain 1 if it was" - https://womble.decadent.org.uk/blog/experiments-with-signed-kernels-and-modules-in-debian.html

Comment: What version Ubuntu are you running?  I thought 16.04 started complaining about unsigned kernel modules (like Nvidia) with secure boot enabled.

Comment: Secure boot is enabled. Keys are in PK. I running Ubuntu 16.10. Yes, from 16.04 I sign modules by myself, my keys are in db so Nvidia or Virtual Box works without any problems. But now I see that I'm able to load unsigned Linux image and then load unsigned modules.

Comment: So secure boot is not working. File a bug report - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1401532